# Permutations and combinations textbook recommendations

Tags: reference-request, permutations, self-learning, combinations

I have had real difficulty with permutation/combination questions in probability and statistics texts. What I have real difficulty with is transforming word problems into mathematical form to solve. Are there any recommendations for a good text that might help me to do this? Or any suggestions for how to tackle these sorts of problems.

Thanks

Comment: Has anybody used Faticoni's "Combinatorics: An introduction"? Is it any good, it seems to cover the required areas going by the table of contents.

Comment: You could try *Mathematics of Choice* by Ivan Niven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for references on combinatorics. There are many lecture notes around the 'net, hiding under names like "discrete mathematics" (elementary combinatorics of the sort you are looking for is one of the main dishes in such a course).

Perhaps the best reference for self study is Kenneth Bogart's ["Combinatorics through Guided Discovery"](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/news-resources/electronic/kpbogart/ComboNoteswHints11-06-04.pdf). Another good resource is Bogart, Drysdale, Stein ["Discrete Math for Computer Science Students"](http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~bagchi/courses/discrete-book/fullbook.pdf). Both are available in full as PDFs for free.

Comment: Thanks. The first one looks good, but seems to cover more than what I wanted to find out- for example, will understanding how groups act on sets help to solve counting problems? Still they are free and I will check them out. I also found [these notes from MIT OCW that look useful](http://ocw.mit.edu/high-school/mathematics/combinatorics-the-fine-art-of-counting/lecture-notes/MITHFH_lecturenotes_2.pdf)

Comment: @user183974, group action on sets is a general way to view many combinatorics setups. Probably much more than you require right now, true.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend [Schaum's Outline of Combinatorics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00Y4RKV0E) by V. K. Balakrishnan.

It contains lots of small examples that are manageable by a beginner, and shows you *how to do it* in a straightforward manner.

Answer (score 1):

As an elementary textbook on statistics, Michael Sullivan's [Statistics: Informed Decisions Using Data](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321757270) is good.

Comment: I had a look at the table of contents, there does not seem to be very much there around counting problems. My issue is not with understanding stats generally, it is with counting problems.

Comment: You'd be hard pressed to find an entire book just about permutation/combinations.  It's not evident from the table of contents, but the Sullivan book has a good explanation of these kinds of problems.  If no book seems to be to your liking, hiring a private tutor is a good idea as well.

Comment: Ah thanks. I will try and get it from my library.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to start out with **Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications** by Kenneth H. Rosen.
The 6th chapter about **Counting** will give you a good edge over permutations and combinations, and you'll able to intuitively solve problems in no time.